# How can I ensure that a Vimeo thumbnail image loaded is always at a higher resolution?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm having an issue with the thumbnail that is being loaded as a placeholder image a video.
For some videos I'm getting a really small image which when covering the size of the container is really pixelated.
Is there a way that I can ensure that the quality of the image selected is at eg. 1200? or what is determining what resolution is selected?
This is my code for getting the thumbnail as a background image below.

```
    const getThumbnail = () => {
        // New request
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Make a GET request to Vimeo's API using the video ID
        const url = `https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/${someID}`
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    // If we get a response, parse as a JSON object
                    const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    // Set the placeholder image to the thumbnail image
                    video.style = `background-image: url(\'${response.thumbnail_url}\' );"`
                }
            }
        };
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using their Oembed API you can specify the height and width using query parameters in the url of the request

```
const url = `https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/${someID}&width=1280&height=720`
```

This will return a thumbnail with dimensions closest to the dimensions you provide

Comment: hmm unfortunately this doesn't work :-( Several videos on one page and the lower ones are really small :-/

Comment: you can scale the images to fit though?

Comment: unfortunately it's scaling but looks pixelated because the image is so small